# React-Redux: onClick function is not working says "this.props.selectDog is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux, and I'm making a simple Redux app. By default there's a list of dogs and if I click one of the button I can see the detail about the selected dog. Right now if I click the button it says "this.props.selectDog is not a function". In console there's no dog inside of selectedDog object, instead it says "selectedDog: function bindActionCreator()". How do I fix this error?

```
Action Creator

export const selectDog = (dogs) => {
    return {
        type: 'SELECT_DOG',
        payload: dogs
    };
};
```

```
Reducer

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const dogsReducer = () => {
    return [
        { "breed": "Beagle", "characteristics": "playful" },
        { "breed": "Golden Retriever",  "characteristics": "calm" },
        { "breed": "Corgi",  "characteristics": "bright" },
        { "breed": "Goldendoodle",  "characteristics": "gentle" },
        { "breed": "Labrador Retriever",  "characteristics": "loyal" }
    ];
};

const selectedDogReducer = (selectedDog = null, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'SELECT_DOG') {
        return action.payload;
    }

    return selectedDog;
}

export default combineReducers({
    dogs: dogsReducer,
    selectedDog: selectedDogReducer
})
```

```
DogList.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectDog } from '../actions';

class DogList extends React.Component {

    renderList() {
        return this.props.dogs.map(dog => {
            console.log(this.props);
            return (
                <div key={dog.breed}>
                    <p>{dog.breed}<br />                   
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.selectedDog(dog)}>SELECT</button></p>
                    <br />
                </div>
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { dogs: state.dogs };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    selectedDog: selectDog
})(DogList);
```

```
DogDetail.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const DogDetail = ({dogs}) => {
    if (!dogs) {
        return <div>Select a Dog!</div>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Dog Detail:</h3>
            <p>{dogs.breed}<br />
            {dogs.characteristics}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { dog: state.selectedDog }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DogDetail);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `DogDetails.js` prop, you need to replace all `dogs` by `dog` :

```
const DogDetail = ({dog}) => {
    if (!dog) {
        return <div>Select a Dog!</div>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Dog Detail:</h3>
            <p>{dog.breed}<br />
            {dog.characteristics}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

(Edit: that's not the answer to the original issue in the title, Giang Le's answer fixed it)

Edit2: dog prop is coming from your redux state, you are mapping it with the `connect()` HOC by doing :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { dog: state.selectedDog }
};
connect(mapStateToProps)(DogDetail);
```

The original issue (`this.props.selectDog` is not a function) is fixed in `DogList.js` by mapping the right action name to dispatch in your component (second argument of `connect()`).

I recommend you to read this link to learn more about the 2nd argument of `connect()` (mapDispatchToProps) (we define it as an object here) :

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object

Comment: Thank you!! It worked! I think I tried that solution too, but that time didn't work. It's not a typo, I just didn't know what to put. To be honest I'm not sure where that dog come from. It's not the same dog in payload?

Answer (score 1):

Correct function name is `selectedDog` instead of `selectDog`. Try `this.props.selectedDog('Corgi')`. Or change to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    selectDog,
})(DogList);
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on that part. I fixed that part, but the detail is still not showing up.

Comment: Sure! Reducer is the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to dispatch your actions in order to fire them from your component.
You can read more here: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: I forgot to put the whole code, but I think that dispatch part is solved by something like Provider and createStore. I added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to dispatch redux action

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { dogs: state.dogs };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { selectDog : (selectDog) => dispatch(selectDog) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DogList);
```